# Time Date Calculation Wrong output

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i am using laravel 5.5 trying to calculate days and multiply with price

working fine when i select date from drop down but when i type date calculation doing wrong what's happening i don't know

here is my controller

```
$pick = Carbon::parse($request->input('pickdate'));
$drop = Carbon::parse($request->input('dropdate'));

$lengthday = $pick->diffInDays($drop, false);

$ptime = str_replace([' '], '', $request->pickuptime);
$dtime = str_replace([' '], '', $request->droptime);
$picktime = Carbon::parse($ptime);
$droptime = Carbon::parse($dtime);

$lengthmin = $picktime->diffInMinutes($droptime, false);
$car = Car::where('slug', $car)->firstorfail();

$cprice = $car->price;
if ($lengthmin >= '1') {
    $minprice = $car->price;
}
else
{
    $minprice = '0';
}
$price = $cprice*$lengthday+$minprice;

if ($price <= '0') {
    return back()->with('warning', 'Please Enter Valid Date & Time');
}
```

here is my view

```
<div class="form-date-w3-agileits">
    <div class="form-agileits">
        <label>Pickup Date :</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-agileits-2">
        <input type="date" name="pickupdate" style="width: 92%;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        padding: 13px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        font-weight: 100;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        margin-bottom: 1.4em;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
        font-family: 'Amaranth', sans-serif;
        color: #bbb9b9;" required=""> 
    </div>  
    <div class="clear"> </div>            
</div>
```

Comment: Typo? `$request->input('pickdate')` Your field is named `pickupdate`

Comment: Hard to help when you don't tell us what you input when it works, and what you input when it doesn't work....

Comment: its work fine when someone select date from drop down its not working when someone type date from keyboard try for booking on
http://www.xrentc.com

Comment: So is it because the user enters a date in a different format?

Comment: @RiggsFolly how can i fix this?

Comment: @SidHeart use validation to not allow users to use not valid dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, you've said you have problems only when users enter the date manually. You need to use the [`date`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-date) validation rule to allow users to enter only valid dates. For example:

```
'pickdate' => 'date',
'dropdate' => 'date',
```

Then you'll be sure Carbon will be able to parse the input data.

Comment: i added current date as value and it fixed validation give me error